# Least squares constrained by fixing the average of the predictions

Tags: reference-request, least-squares

I am unsure whether this question is more suited for mathSE or CrossValidated, but since I am a mathematician I will post it here.

> Are there any well-known methods to perform a least square estimation
>   with a constraint on the mean of the estimates?

Namely, suppose we have observations $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and responses $y_i\in \mathbb{R}$, I would like to find a linear model
$$\hat y_i = \beta_0+\beta^Tx_i$$
minimizing square errors
$$RSS = \sum_{i=1}^N(\hat y_i - y_i)^2$$
under the condition that
$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\hat y_i = c$$
for some given $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. we want the average of the predictions to be $c$).

I have tried working out the 1-dimensional case $n=1$, but of course the solution is trivial and given by the constant model $\hat y = c$ (to see this easily, notice that we have two parameters to estimate, the constraint reduces the freedom to one single variable so that the solution is unique, and the constant model fits the bill).

Higher dimensional cases seem pretty messy to me. I've tried working in general, but with scarce results. However, I am not an expert in this kind of computations, so i was wondering if someone can do better or if this kind of model has been widely studied (I would actually expect so, as it is a pretty natural constraint to consider in some cases).

Comment: Possibly useful to search for [constrained least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_least_squares)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I have already taken a (admittedly quick) look, but I wasn't able to find anything on the case I'm interested in. Constrained least squares seems more focused on putting constraints on the coefficients (such as asking that they are intergers) than on the output of the model.

Comment: I see. But with your constraint on the predicted values, isn't that just placing an equality constraint on the coefficients? And that Wikipedia link refers to "Equality constrained least squares" in one of its bullet points.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth You might be correct. I will check the literature and see if I find something that fits.